# Streaming from Python logging/stdout to a redis connection

Tags: python, logging, redis

How can I stream Python stdout (or logging) to a redis connection?

There is a long running job that I need to capture logs for in realtime. It's not feasible to wait until the job is finished to get the logs, in case of failure there needs to be record of what happened.

I have managed to capture logging output to stdout in a StringIO buffer that can be read when the long running job is finished.

What I can't figure out is how to get that buffer to interact with the redis client in realtime, while the job is still running.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out:

```
from io import StringIO


class RedisHandler(StringIO):

    def __init__(self, key, redis_client):
        """
        Create a new StringIO interface for the given key and redis_client.
        """

        StringIO.__init__(self)
        self.key = key
        self.redis_client = redis_client

    def write(self, record):
        """
        Publish record to redis logging list
        """

        self.redis_client.lpush(self.key, record)
```

In the main script, I redirect stdout + stderr to a RedisHandler instance. Redis acts as the endpoint for StringIO and adds each row from the log output to a list.

Comment: Great solution! I'm wondering how's the performance of storing logs in a redis list, like redis can handle a list storing logs for up to 10K items, etc.